# What is the name/adjective of a human who doesn't believe in God but s/he is honest and does good in his/her life?

Tags: atheists

I know a person who doesn't believe in God is an atheist but this name can't convey the reality of that human.

There are many theists who are liar,violent,dishonest,prejudice and cheater but there are also many atheists who are honest,open-minded,kind and just.

What does Islam call a person owner of this good character but atheist?

Answer (score -5, accepted):

From what I know, a person only answers to god about his/her beliefs and to no one else. One can't judge another because of his beliefs-- but only for his good deeds.

Comment: How does this answer the question?

Answer (score 3):

An atheist is specifically called a Dahri دهري , derived from the verse:

> وقالوا ما هي إلا حياتنا الدنيا نموت ونحيا وما يهلكنا إلا **الدهر** وما لهم بذلك من علم إن هم إلا يظنون
>
> And they say, "There is not but our worldly life; we die and live, and nothing destroys us except time." And they have of that no knowledge; they are only assuming.
>
> <sup>— [Quran 45:24](http://quran.com/45/24)</sup>

There isn't any term which differentiates between atheists depending on a portion of their deeds. Nor does Islam ascribe any weight to their deeds (see [47:8](https://quran.com/47/8)  etc.)

Answer (score 0):

If a person disbelieve Allah and other beliefs he is a disbeliever. Allah will not measure deeds of polytheists, hypocrites and disbelievers. They will enter hellfire without measuring deeds for eternity. One must have faith to enter paradise if he does bad deeds he will enter the paradise at last after purification from sins.

Reference:https://islamqa.info/en/answers/13350/if-kaafirs-have-good-morals-will-they-enter-paradise-will-the-children-of-the-kuffaar-enter-paradise

Comment: The question is about terminology not about their destiny.

Answer (score 0):

A man or woman who does not believe in God, in most cases, do not know what is right and wrong in many things. Religion means 'the way of life'. If a person does do good deeds in this life, he must do it for a reason, that is for his Afterlife. Please think a little about this answer. Hope this helps.

And Allah knows best.

Comment: This simply disagrees with the statement of the prophet "I was sent to perfect good character." [al-Muwatta'](https://sunnah.com/urn/516220) which according al-Mubarakpuri means that good morals already existed in the pre islamic Arab culture it rather needs to be improved.